# How does the Thomas-Kilmann Conflict Mode Instrument relate to the Big Five?

Tags: personality, io-psychology, big-five, conflict

The [Thomas-Kilmann Conflict Mode Instrument](https://www.opp.com/-/media/Files/PDFs/Reports-in-English/TKI/TKI-Profile-and-Interpretive-Report-US-English-Pat-Sample.pdf) (TKI) is [apparently](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1013280109471) quite popular in MBA classes and even in conflict negotiation practice:

> The TKI is popular beyond the confines of negotiation classes.
>   Indeed, it is one of the most widely used instruments of its kind in the
>   world.

It basically scores one's negotiation style in five domains: Competing, Collaborating, Compromising, Avoiding, and Accommodating, although it looks like these are placed on just two dimensions Assertiveness and Cooperativeness.

[image]

(The also have an [interesting FAQ](https://www.kilmanndiagnostics.com/frequently-asked-questions-about-tki-assessment) as to why they chose this domain approach: apparently to avoid halo and  social desirability effects in questions/answers.)

Has the TKI been [co]related to the Big Five or some other more general (i.e. not simply focused on conflict-resolution) personality model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few studies that have correlated Big 5 with conflict styles. There are various terminology and measures but many use a similar set of five styles to the TKI.

Antonioni (1998) is highly cited. Here are the correlations.

[image: big 5 and conflict styles]

In short:

- The five conflict styles are correlated in ways that partially reflect the underlying two-dimensions of interested in self and interested in others.
- Agreeableness correlates positively with interested in others and avoiding conflict. Agreeableness is also the strongest correlate of conflict styles.
- Extraversion and openness are both related to integrating and negatively related to avoiding conflict.
- Conscientiousness is related to integrating.
- Neuroticism is related to avoiding conflict.

Antonioni, D. (1998). Relationship between the big five personality factors and conflict management styles. International journal of conflict management, 9(4), 336-355.

Answer (score 0):

I am personally accredited in the TKI and before answering the question here is my take:

1. TKI is an instrument based on a theory. If neuroscience is your thing, my guess is that you would prefer theories to be based on data (as the Big Five is’ then derive an instrument from that.
2. I have not seen much in the way of empirical research around the TKI, however as a guess I would hazard the following:

Accommodating may correlate with high trait Agreeableness.

Avoiding may correlate with high trait Neuroticism

Competing may correlate with low trait Agreeableness

Personally I think the only value of TKI is to surface how individuals interact with one another. But the problem is that this can create a false awareness - if something is a TRAIT then it is quite hard to change. Better imho to stick with the Big Five and derive an understanding of how you handle conflict from that.